# C# and .Net Syntax Explained

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am new to C# and don't.

Can someone please explain why `passwordHash` was able to be assigned to `user.PasswordHash` despite `passwordHash` only being declared as an argument of a method?

```
     public async Task<ServiceResponse<int>> Register(User user, string password)
        {
            CreatePasswordHash(password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt);

            user.PasswordHash = passwordHash;
            user.PasswordSalt = passwordSalt;

            ...

        }

       private void CreatePasswordHash(string password, out byte[] passwordHash, out byte[] passwordSalt)
        {
            var hmac = new System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256()
            using (hmac)
            {
                passwordSalt = hmac.Key;
                passwordHash = hmac.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, passwordHash is passed an an "out" parameter, which means it has a value set by the method it's passed to, that can then be used for subsequent computation after the method completes.  It's a way of, in effect, returning more than one thing from a method and is also how all the TryParse methods work.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier for more.

Comment: Though the way we should "return more than one thing" is to use a custom type, or something built in like one of the various tuple offerings. The OP's code doesn't have the simplicity of TryParse so I would advocate not following its pattern